# Python: os.path.realpath() - how to fix unescaped backslashes?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I want to get the path to the currently executed script.I have used
`os.path.realpath(__file__)`, however, it returns a string like `D:\My Stuff\Python\my_script.py` without proper backslash escaping! How to escape them?

Comment: I think there is some underlying confusion here... you need to escape a string when you put the string inside a Python source code file, however, you don't need to escape a string in memory once Python is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
path = "D:\My Stuff\Python\my_script.py"
escaped_path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\")
print(escaped_path)
```

Will output

```
D:\\My Stuff\\Python\\my_script.py
```

Comment: Or better r'\' and r'\\'

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you may appreciate the built-in `repr` function to get a "printable representation of an object"
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr

```
path = 'D:\My Stuff\Python\my_script.py'
print(path)
D:\My Stuff\Python\my_script.py
print(repr(path))
'D:\\My Stuff\\Python\\my_script.py'
```

Comment: `repr()` will not fix the problem (at least in Python 3.4).